# Serverless Framework lambda function not assuming default api role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I have deployed an API Gateway via the Serverless Framework with a default IAM role (apis-gateway-dev-apiDefaultRole) that contains a set of permissions.  Each lambda function is declared separately, and does **not** have an IAM role defined in serverless.yml.

If I understand correctly, Serverless now generates minimal lambda IAM roles to each lambda fn (eg app-apis-fn-dev-fn), assigns them minimal permissions to write logs, but then assumes permissions from the default role.

My lambda functions now throw AccessDenied errors:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetParameter operation: User: arn:aws:sts::************:assumed-role/app-apis-fn-dev-region-lambdaRole/app-apis-fn-dev-fn is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter ...
```

app-apis-fn-dev-region-lambdaRole is the minimal role autogenerated by Serverless.  It doesn't have permissions.  The permissions are in apis-gateway-dev-apiDefaultRole

This seems to imply to me that the lambda is not assuming the apiDefaultRole - is that correct?  How do I troubleshoot this?

The worst bit is it worked fine before some fairly major changes I made earlier today, but the role definitions were one of the few parts that were not changed... I know I've broken it, please help me work out how!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Serverless Framework creates minimal roles for each Lambda.

You should simply extend them with additional permissions that are needed to all Lambdas:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  iam:
    role:
      statements: # permissions for all of your functions can be set here
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - ssm:GetParameter
          Resource: <param arn goes here>
```

Source: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#permissions

It's not a perfect solution, because it will be applied to all functions, so if you want to have the least privilege applied to each function, you can use this plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-iam-roles-per-function

```
functions:
  func1:
    handler: handler.get
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow        
        Action:
          - ssm:GetParameter    
        Resource: <param arn goes here>
```